# how to write a function wrapper with correct TS props checking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So basically for my use case, assume we have these functions

```
const fn1 = ({level, type}) => { console.log(level,type)}
const fn2 = ({level, username}) => { console.log(level,username)}
const fn3 = ({level, age}) => { console.log(level,age)}
```

Now I have 2 components that calling these functions,

```
const Component1 = () => { 
   const {level} = useGetUserInfo();
   useEffect((fn1({level, type: 1})) => {}, [])
}

const Component2 = () => { 
   const {level} = useGetUserInfo();
   useEffect((fn2({level, username: 'username'})) => {}, [])
   useEffect((fn3({level, age: '27'})) => {}, [])

}
```

so as you can see, the part to get level is the same between two components, and I dont want this to happen (in reality, other than level, there is a set of common information taking from different places which making the code longer and more repeated)

So what I want to achieve is write a custom hook that take in the fn array and return the wrapper fn

So that i can write like this

```
const Component1 = () => { 
   const [returnFn1] = useWrapperFn(fn1);
   useEffect((returnFn1({type: 1})) => {}, []). // --> here i dont need to pass level anymore
}

const Component2 = () => { 
   const [returnFn2, returnFn3] = useWrapperFn(fn2,fn3);
   useEffect((returnFn2({username: 'username'})) => {}, []) // --> no need to pass in level
   useEffect((returnFn3({age: '27'})) => {}, []) // --> no need to pass in level
}
```

so far this is my hook **that appriciate your help to give feedback for fixing**:

```
const useWrapperFn = <T extends any[]>(fns: ((...args: T) => void)[]) => {
   const {level} = useGetUserInfo();

  const returnFns = fns.map((fn) => {
    return ((...args: any[]) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      fn({ ...args[0], level}); //-> here i inject the level
    }) as (props: Omit<NonNullable<Parameters<typeof fn>[0]>, 'level'>) => void;
  });

  return returnFns;
};

export default useWrapperFn;
```

What I want is when i used the returnFn, **it should still having correct props type checking for the remaining fields.** For example when I called returnFn1 and doesnt pass in `type`, TS error will be prompt.

```
returnFn1({type: 1}) // -> works 
returnFn1() // -> will throw ts error missing type
```

**Current behavior**

Currently JS wise, the logic is correct

For TS lint check wise, it is working with Component 1 ( passing only 1 fn to array)

However, for Component2 (passing more than 1 fn), then the TS lint will be a combination of all function props

This would mean that

```
returnFn2({username: 'username'}) // --> currently prompt that missing `age` , wherease `age` belong to fn3

returnFn3({age: '27'}) // --> currently prompt that missing `usernamse` , wherease `username` belong to fn2
```

So is there anyway to modify my useWrapperFn hook, so that the returnedFn arrays it return will have correct props type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you need a strong and tight type declaration:

```js
const useWrapperFn = <T extends ((...args: any[]) => any)[]>(fns: [...T]): {
  [K in keyof T]: (props: Omit<NonNullable<Parameters<T[K]>[0]>, 'level'>) => void
} => {
  const { level } = useGetUserInfo();

  const returnFns = fns.map((fn) => {
    return ((...args: any[]) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      fn({ ...args[0], level }); //-> here i inject the level
    })
  });

  return returnFns as any;
};
```

Demo: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgdQE4EMAOnGoGJgwC8MAPACoyIAeUiYAJhDABQsB0n6qA5hAFwx0YAJ4BtALoBKYgD4hoqZNksAZpEFjO7ctMEBvAFAwYYgNIwAloQDWiESFUxdglplQhMAmAHkAtpZQpABy4MFwADYR6ABGEYikAArc6H6IdKgQFOYSsmIADLkANDAA5PEAbogRpbIyRPIVIJYMhgC+cjBGJqCQsPowldUwHSQDQxGCAIwjhsYwvdAwqOlwqGAEzCTqEOx+WGzq9fLdJsur66wcXLzewuLSnadnMAD0rzAAAlAQALSWPDAIBW8xe6hYA203D4BQkJQmIykAG43q9fvIABa4RBWKxgABWiGAsCgWMGiCqEVBiPmbWRcxMKyga0ITJZmyEzHuSPaPMMi1gK2I8CQaCwOHwYBYYhYniglnABhgFTgiEEYDgfhiuERnXyJVlmHliq6MAgcAYIHVmu1qF1DRgU2khhWsIh8xVapg+XaUhdiDETvdJnNlsEPrp-rdp1DVu9vqAA

Comment: hi , thanks for your answer. There is an edge case, what if 'vue' is also a common field, when this happen, i need to modify the props to props: Omit<NonNullable<Parameters<T[K]>[0]>, 'level' | 'vue'>

But after doing this , if i call 

re[0]({
  sudo: 0 //-this doesnt prompt any error, but it should because sudo not a correct field for re[0]
})

Comment: do you have any ideas to fix this edge case ? tks

Comment: if you set omit to any existing properties typescript will pass them to legacy state don't worry about them your code will always overwrite

Comment: actually i found another way, that is change Omit to Optional , it will serve my case. Thanks for the answer